# What's wrong with this xargs command?

Tags: shell, xargs

Consider the output:

```
% { echo one; echo two; echo three; } | xargs -I{} -L1 echo test-{} 
test-{} one
test-{} two
test-{} three
```

Why doesn't `{}` get substituted as per the manual page (and my memory, too)?

How to change the command line to get `test-one`, `test-two`, `test-three` lines as output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the `-L 1`; it is implied by `-I` (as the man page says), but it would override it when specified afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

It works without "-L1", because it is implicitly set.

```
{ echo one; echo two; echo three; } | xargs -I{} echo test-{}
test-one
test-two
test-three
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed you can do this:

```
{ echo one; echo two; echo three; } | parallel echo test-{}
```

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to learn more:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1